# Spring Batch + JPA + PostgreSQL current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am facing an issue described in the following example. I am using Spring Batch ItemWriter for inserting data into the database. After the data import is successful, I also want to insert the batch status into another table. However, Postgres doesn't allow me to do so if there was a failing query before.

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobScope;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@JobScope
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CsvWriter implements ItemWriter<List<CsvEntity>> {

  // these are org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
  DataRepository dataRepository;
  BatchStatusRepository batchStatusRepository;

  @Override
  public void write(List<? extends List<DataEntity>> data) {
    Long batchId = data.get(0).get(0).getBatchId(); // each data belongs to a batch with batch id;
    try {
      csvRepository.saveAll(data.get(0)); // save data

      batchStatusRepository.save( // if data was ok, write status Ok
        BatchStatusEntity.builder()
          .batchId(batchId)
          .status("Ok")
          .build());
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) { // if there is inconsistency in data (duplicates), I want to set an Error status
      log.error("Duplicate entity", e);

      batchStatusRepository.save( // this throws org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
        BatchStatusEntity.builder()
          .batchId(batchId)
          .status("Error")
          .build());
      }
  }
}
```

From what I understand, I need to rollback the first transaction, but I don't know how. I tried to separate **saveAll** into separate method with `@Transactional(value = "transactionManager", rollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Don't. Use a seperate listener like a job or steplistener for that that uses a **new** transaction to write this. Also this writer looks like should have been a `Tasklet`, all in all it looks a bit weird.

Comment: Each batch is a chunk with size of one, which reads one CSV file. The example may look weird, but the issue here is the **transaction** thingy. I have tried doing the same in **ItemWriteListener** but with the same result.

Comment: As stated you should write it with a *new* transaction and not as part of the current transaction (as you do now). Still weird as this would also break the retry mechanism.

Comment: Do you know what makes the transaction ? I don't use **@Transactional** anywhere.

Comment: Which is what your problem is, you should put that piece of code inside a transactional method that starts a new transaction. So move that to a separate component which itself is `@Transactional`.